# Powershell Script to export directory folders and owners (excluding files)

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0

I am trying to export all folders including child folders within a file share on a remote server alongside the owner info as shown (Note I do not need info re the files within the folders)

```
get-childitem \\fileshare\folder -recurse | get-acl  | select-object path,owner,accesstostring,group | export-csv “C:\security.csv”
```

Whilst this works to a degree it includes all files and not specifically folders within the directory. Note I have also created a temp PS Drive to minimize folder naming length;

```
new-psdrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share\folder1\folder2\folder3
```

Can someone please assist?

Comment: You're simply trying to restrict your `Get-ChildItem` to directories and exclude the files?  Did you try adding the `-Directory` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Hi that's correct. I have tried viewing other resources before asking the question and found the following  Get-ChildItem \\myserver\myshare\myshare\ -Directory | Select-Object -Property name |  convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation  | Out-File c:\temp\mydirectorylist.csv  Using the directory parameter in the code provided abooce returns an error

Comment: What error?  In your example in the comment above you didn't use `-Recurse` with `-Directory` so you'll get only the immediate child directories.  I don't have a share available at the moment, but I suspect you may have problems pulling the ACLs off remote shares.

Answer (score 1):

Then check for folders with either the `-Directory` parameter of Get-ChildItem present in recent Powershell versions or use this:

```
Get-Childitem \\fileshare\folder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
  Get-Acl | 
    Select-Object Path,Owner,Accesstostring,Group | 
      Export-Csv “C:\security.csv”
```

( I prefer a more readable variant of this technical still one liner )

Comment: thank you i get the following error  Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "PSIsContainer" value of type "System.String" type"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:1 char:49
+ Get-Childitem C:\p1admin -Recurse | Where-Object <<<<  PSIsContainer |Get-Acl | Select-Object Path,Owner,Accesstostri
ng,Group | Export-Csv "C:\security.csv"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId :CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: It works here with either variant. Might be a rights/double hop problem.

Comment: Try replacing the `Where-Object` part with `Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}`

Comment: Thank you all! To confirm it was a rights issue the account I was running the ps command as didn't have sufficient permissions.